# Sharepoint change password webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory

I have created a webpart in which it uses AccountManagement namespace methods to change the current users password but this message shows up:

Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.

Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: put code you are using in your webpart and where exactly its giving you the above exception.

Comment: ok let me check .

Comment: Exception comes where I call the ChangePassword(oldPasswordValue, newPasswordValue); (ChangePassword)

Comment: yup that's the method, you need to give the code within this method "ChangePassword"

Comment: give the code ? sorry I didnt get what you said

Comment: Bro, you need to show the code as how your webpart is trying to change password, as otherwise no one would know whats wrong, the part "ChangePassword(oldPasswordValue, newPasswordValue);" is just a little bit of code, Let me know if you need explanation in urdu ;)

Comment: ChangePassword is the common method inside namespace System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, I am using its method to changepassword of the current user.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I was thinking different way, is your code within http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx and also if you put add all of code, I can try and see what could be wrong, as it could be the application pool account that doesn't have enough permission on AD OU

Comment: I think I need to confirm the application pool account rights on AD OU, from the network admin. Because, the same code is working on other different domains and locally with ADAM.